# How do I program a while loop for this specific situation?

Tags: python, while-loop

Create the function execChoice(choice).
o Using the Python way of doing a switch statement that utilizes the dictionary object with the name choices, invoke the function from the dictionary that has the key specified by the string choice passed into the function.

▪ May the check case insensitive by uppercasing the string in the variable
choice before checking to see if it matches a key in the dictionary.

o If the key is not in the dictionary, the default function in the MenuOptions module should be invoked.

For the while loop in question:

• Create the variable choice and assign an empty string to it.

• Create a while loop that will not stop until the value for the variable choice is the value 'X'.
This check should be case insensitive.

• In the while loop:

o Invoke the getChoice function in the Menu module and assign the return value to the variable choice.
o Invoke the execChoice function in the Menu module and pass the variable choice to that function.

I have correctly done similar coding in previous situations, however, this one has had me halted. I cannot seem to get past this while loop part, and I am also having issues with the situation above it.

```
def execChoice(choice):
    choices = 
          {
           "S": showPilots(),
           "A": addPilot(),
           "D": deletePilot(),
           "X": done()
           }
    if dict.keys() not in choices:
        default()


from .Menu import *

choice = []
while choice is True:
    choice = getChoice(Menu)
'''
Cannot figure out what i need to add after this
'''
```

The expected results are supposed to be what is described in the description above, and the loops/functions should be functioning correctly according to directions. (Not run yet, just working with no syntax or other errors).

Comment: `"S": showPilots,` to get a string => function not function call. Then, lots of other errors.

Comment: `choice = []
while choice is True:`: does not enter the loop

Comment: Okay, what should I put to replace them? I am learning Python as I go so this has got me a little out of shape.

Comment: Have you looked at the tutorial I suggested in a comment on your previous (deleted) question?

Comment: Yes. I still have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're defining that dictionary, it is *actually calling* the `showPilots()` function, the `addPilot()` function, etc.

I think the dictionary is intended to hold the *function objects*, but not actually *call* them:

```
def execChoice(choice):
    choices = {
        "S": showPilots,
        "A": addPilot,
        "D": deletePilot,
        "X": done
    }
    if choice in choices:
        return choices[choice]
    else:
        return default
```

And then you would call it like this:

```
# get the function we are supposed to call
f = execChoice(user_input)
# now execute the function
f()
```

Comment: Okay awesome! This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much! I was not sure if I was doing the if statement correctly, which relied on what was above it. Do you know what I would need to do for the while loop?

Comment: Only addition I would make to this excellent answer: In python, style guidelines are to use `snake_case` for function definitions, not `mixedCapitalization` e.g., `def exec_choice(choice):`